# Does git checkout origin/master also do an up to date pull?

Tags: git

If I got git checkout origin/master, I see that it creates a detached HEAD state with no specific branch. But does it also pull the latest from origin/master? I think it does not, but  saw some person referring to new versions of git that do that. Therefore, I wanted to confirm.

Comment: It would be disastrous if it did.

Comment: Can you provide links to what says that it does?

Comment: It was a forum where I saw that, so I was suspicious.

Answer (score 3):

`git checkout` *never* does an implicit `pull`, no matter what version of git you have.

Comment: Nor does it do an implicit `fetch`, which is what actually gathers new stuff from the remote repository... `pull` is equivalent to `fetch` followed by a `merge`.